# parse dirty object is not working after migration

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-platform, mean-stack

I have a question regarding parse cloud code. The following cloud code was working before migration written in cloud code but after migration its not returning desired output.

```
var streamClass = Parse.Object.extend("Streams");
        streamObj = new streamClass({
            objectId: "dummy",
            streamerId: usersArr[i]
        });
        streamObj.dirty = function() {return false;};
```

There are two entities i.e. streams and users. Every user has streams. So there is users pointer(streamerId) in stream table. If user do not have any stream created then i am creating a stream dummy object and setting user(streamerId) as a pointer in stream object. When this code was called as a API, it was returning stream dummy object with user(streamerId) information before parse server migration. After migration the above code gives the following output.

```
{
"result": [
    {
        "__type": "Pointer",
        "className": "Streams",
        "objectId": "dummy"
    }
]
```

}

It can noticed that there is no user(streamerId) information in the output. Can anyone please help me in this regard.

I am not saving this streamObj. I am returning this streamObj to IOS app. I also tested it through postman in google chrome. The following is a complete function which takes array of users object and array of streams objects and return one object contains user and its related streams.

```
function getUsersAndRecentStreams(usersArr, streamsArr) {
var responseObj = [];
var moment = require('moment');
var now = moment();
var currentDate = new Date();
for( var i=0; i<usersArr.length; i++ ) {
    var streamObj = null;
    for( j=0; j<streamsArr.length; j++ ) {

        var streamerObj =  streamsArr[j].get('streamerId');
        if( streamerObj.id === usersArr[i].id ) {
            if( moment(streamsArr[j].get('showTimeStart'))  <= now && moment(streamsArr[j].get('showTimeEnd'))  >= now ) {
                streamObj = streamsArr[j];
                break;
            }

            if( streamObj == null) {
                streamObj = streamsArr[j];
            } 
            else {
                if( moment(streamsArr[j].get('showTimeStart'))  <= now ) {
                    streamObj = streamsArr[j];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if( streamObj == null ) {
        var streamClass = Parse.Object.extend("Streams");
        streamObj = new streamClass({
            objectId: "dummy",
            streamerId: usersArr[i]
        });
        streamObj.dirty = function() {return false;};
        var streamObj = new streamObj();
    }
    responseObj.push(streamObj);
}

return responseObj;
```

}

There are two cases.
1) When streamObj is not null. In this case the output is correct.
2) The second case when streamObj is null. In this case the following output is return which is not desired.

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "Streams",
            "objectId": "dummy"
        }
    ]
}
```

When streamObj is null, The following desired output should return this function.

```
    {
    "result": [
        {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "Streams",
            "objectId": "dummy",
            "StreamerId": userObject   
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: could you provide how you save streamObj , and how to get this object(how to build query, or using get/fetch)?

Comment: Hi ChunTingLin, Thanks for your reply. I have updated my question with more information you asked. I am not saving this streamObj. Actually i am returning this object to IOS app. Please see my updated question.

Comment: so you have a cloud function which response.success(getUsersAndRecentStreams(arg1, arg2)). What is the desired output?

Comment: Yes, my cloud code is returning response.success(getUsersAndRecentStreams(arg1, arg2)). I have updated my question and wrote about the desired output about the function.

Comment: Parse.com not use javascript sdk to execute cloud functions, so get different result. Override the dirty function is not a elegant way, once api implement changed may get different results(even uncaught Errors).

Comment: I can't find a good way to trick the javascript sdk. But there is a simple solution to get what you desired, set streamObj  to the format directly.
 streamObj = {
                "__type": "Pointer",
                "className": "Streams",
                "objectId": "dummy",
                "StreamerId": userObject
            }

Comment: Thanks ChunTingLin. I got the desired result by using your code.The issue has been resolved.

Comment: ChunTingLin, The issue has been solved and now when i call API from browser i.e. Postman. I receive the userObject in StreamerId. I also call this API from parse server and i received the output of the StreamerId in a same format as i am getting after parse migration on Amazon server. In short there is no issue with code. But when IOS app is hitting this API, it does not receive StreamerId in response. Can you please guide me in this regard?

Comment: Does your IOS app is work before migration? This function is a cloud code? AFAIK, the basic idea of each client sdk is using client-key instead of rest-key. Only GET method from client will transform to POST method to contain body in the request(Android, ok-http). And cloud function is using POST, so I think it will work as restful api. Other different is useless(not important) information in header. If the request.user will result in different result, watch you are using revocable session or legacy-token. Sorry, I'm not familiar with ios sdk.

Comment: Yes, IOS app works when i connect app with parse. It uses the exact same code from parse server. Yes this is cloud code and exposed as rest API. IOS app does not receive streamerId when it connects with parse code after migration. So do you recommend that this cloud code function should be used as REST API instead of using it with IOS sdk.

Comment: I do not use swift, so I can't figure out why streamerId is missing(Class type or something). The parse-server is host by yourself? You can set env variable VERBOSE=1, see the request/response different of IOS sdk from Postman.

Comment: Yes, parse server has been hosted by me on Amazon EC2 instance. I dont know how can i set env Variable VERBOSE=1 on Amazon EC2 instance. I setup parse server on Amazon EC2 instance using beanstalk i.e. Amazon Utility for deployment and instance creation.

Comment: as same as how you setup DATABASE_URI, MASTER_KEY, APP_ID

Comment: or you can do a trick by modify the package.json. Set it(export VERBOSE=1;) before start. 
"scripts": {
    "start": "export VERBOSE=1; node index.js"
  }

Comment: I have set environment variable but still IOS app is not receiving streamerId. I think we will have to use this function as REST API.

Comment: set env variable VERBOSE=1,  is to see the request/response different between ios request and post-man only. After that, the log of parse-server will contain request args and the response, so that you can find out the difference.

Comment: For a time being i have to give up on this issue. I have already spent alot of time on it. I will try it later.

Comment: Good luck. If you have free time to try it, maybe you can tell me the results. Thx

Comment: Offcourse, i will let you know. As you helped me alot. Thanks for your help.